# TestNg: How to a run particular test in a test suite to repeat n times on different parameters

Tags: java, testng

In the following example, I would like to repeat `test4` with different set of parameters on running the testng xml.
My intention is to get all tests to run in sequence but the `test4` should repeat for some set of parameters that I would like to pass.
Is there a way to achieve this?

````
public class SomeTests(){

@Test
public void test1(){
    ...
}
@Test(priority=1)
public void test2(){
     ...
}
@Test(priority=2)
public void test3(){
    ...
}

@Test(priority=3)
public void test4(String param){
    ...
}

} ```
````

Comment: Put parameters in an ArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataProvider` annotation to create a parameter provider and pass it to your test case using `dataProvider` attribute.

In your case it could be something like this:

```
...
@DataProvider(name = "myParamProvider")
public Object[][] myParams() {
 return new Object[][] {
   { "param1"},
   { "param2"}
 };
}


@Test(priority=3, dataProvider = "myParamProvider")
public void test4(String param){
    ...
}
...
```

Or simply by providing the `DataProvider` method name like this:

```
...
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] myParams() {
     return new Object[][] {
       { "param1"},
       { "param2"}
     };
    }
    
    
    @Test(priority=3, dataProvider = "myParams")
    public void test4(String param){
        ...
    }
   ...
```

Check this out for more:
https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders